# What are the differences between using the Link component in react-router and calling `window.history.pushState()` manually?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

in my code when i click button, component `Aaaaa` is not re-rendered, but when i tap on link, component `Aaaaa` is re-rendered. i can't find cause of it?

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
        <button onClick={() => window.history.pushState('','','/about')}>About</button>
        <Link to='/about'>to About</Link>
        <Aaaaaa/>
    </>
  );
}
```

and:

```
Aaaaaa(){
   const location = useLocation()
   return <div>About </div>
}
```

Comment: `window.history.pushState` is not from react-router. Take a look at the docs for the react-router version of that [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

Comment: Also check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) for the native JS version you are currently using. It says "Note that the browser won't attempt to load this URL after a call to pushState(), but it might attempt to load the URL later, for instance after the user restarts the browser"

Comment: not right answer! I mean why `window.history.pushState` cause not rerender component `Aaaaa`? while `window.history.pushState` change location and `Aaaaa` use `useLocation()` hook.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper way is to use `<Link to='/about'>to About</Link>` when trying to navigate manually (by clicking a button) and `window.history.pushState('','','/about')` when trying to navigate automatically (like after completing an API call).

Answer (score 4):

cause window.history.pushState is not using the react router
so you can use link to navigate between the pages.
but if you have limits and you want it to be a buttn and still navigate using react router, you can use history from react-router-dom

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
// some other codes
const { history } = props;
// some other codes
<button onClick={() => history.push('/about')}>About</button>
// some other codes
export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```

or you can use 'useHistory' hook if you're using react-router v5.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
// some other codes
const history = useHistory();
// some other codes
<button onClick={() => history.push('/about')}>About</button>
// some other codes
export default MyComponent
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that `window.history.pushState('','','/about')` does not work as expected. The router does not update what route to display.

If you cant use a  button and need to control the location programatically, but use class components wrap it in a function component like this:

```
... other routes

<Route exact path="/register" component={()=>{
    const history = useHistory();
    return <RegisterPage onRegister={async (account) => {
      this.setState({ account });
      history.push('/'); // sends user automatically to main page
    }} />
  }} />

...
```

Answer (score 2):

window.history.pushState method doesn't trigger any browser event, which in turn doesn't notify react router about the update you made to the history object

React router custom Link component is most likely going to use a custom event or the observer design pattern to be able to notify and respond to changes in the window history object